# Unable to acess contacts with phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have written a code following the documentation on phone gap website`

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // find all contacts
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();

    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) 
    {
        console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
      var element = document.getElementById('cont');

      element.innerHTML='<li><a href="#">' + contacts[i].displayName + '</a></li>';

    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}

</script>`
```

It is working fine in andriod emulator but when i install the application samsung galaxy phone it return a "null". Kindly Help.

Comment: What returns a null? onSuccess?

Comment: yes on success it returns null.

Comment: What is null - contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange... I also got `null`... (using Phonegap version 2.0)

I suggest you use something like `contacts[i].name.formatted` instead of `contacts[i].displayName`.

So, for example, by using `contacts[i].name.formatted`, your code should look like something like this:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // find all contacts
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();

    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {

    var element = document.getElementById('cont'); 
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) 
    {
        console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].name.formatted);                
        element.innerHTML='<li><a href="#">' + contacts[i].name.formatted + '</a></li>';    
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

Here are the different information that you can obtain with `contacts[i].name`:

- `contacts[i].name.givenName` : provides the **given name**
- `contacts[i].name.formatted` : provides a **formatted name** (first name + last name)
- `contacts[i].name.middleName` : provides the **middle name**
- `contacts[i].name.familyName` : provides the **family name** (first name + last name)
- `contacts[i].name.honorificPrefix` : provides the **honorific prefix**
- `contacts[i].name.honorificSuffix` : provides the **honorific suffix**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is a complex problem with simple solution. just added only one line of code

```
 options.filter=""; 
    options.multiple=true;
    var filter = ["*"];
```

That is complete code is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
   // find all contacts
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter=""; 
    options.multiple=true;
    var filter = ["*"];
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);


}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("cont");
    var str = '<ul data-role="listview" >';
  for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {


       str=str + '<li>' + contacts[i].displayName + '</li>';
   }
   str = str + '</ul>';

  // ele.innerHTML = str;
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

And it is working, by the way it also shows some null values as per the contact entries but it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be iOS - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts. The docs say displayName isn't supported there. I'd follow Littm's advice, and also check the doc I linked to here as it talks about what properties don't work across different platforms.